# Trying to calculate value from selected option using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the option value from the dropdown and use Javascript to calculate an output. For example option 3 is selected I need to show the value of 3 * 13.95 and the correct output of 41.85.

```js
function calcVals() {

  var e = document.getElementById("old english");

  var selFrst = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

  var totalCal = +selFrst * 13.95;
  document.getElementById("totalAmount").value = totalCal;
}
```

```html
<div class="">
  Red Leicester Cheese
  <br> 13,25€ per kilo
  <select id="old english" name="oldenglish" onchange="calcVals">
    <option value="0" disabled="" selected=""></option>
    <option value="1">1 Kilo</option>
    <option value="2">2 Kilos</option>
    <option value="3">3 Kilos</option>
    <option value="4">4 Kilos</option>
    <option value="5">5 KiLOS</option>

  </select>
  <br><label for="weight">Enter Weight</label>
  <br>
  <input type="number">
  </select>

  Textbox :

  <input name="totalAmount" id="totalAmount" type="text" readonly>

</div>
```

I tried to get `Javascript` to calculate a sum and give an output once a value was selected from the drop down but it return no value.

Comment: Are you calling the function? Also, Ids should not have spaces.

Comment: Place a dash in your ID => `old-english`, then reference it with `document.getElementById("old-english");` or you can camel case it, `oldEnglish` JS is looking for two separate items there and will not give you the result your looking for. You may also have to parse the equateable numeric options as numbers => `Number()` or `parseInt()` to ensure they are in fact numeric and will properly parse as numbers.